# What is the maximum number of rows that SOQL and SOSL can "scan"?

Tags: soql, sosl

It's quite clear from the [governor limits documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm) how many records can be returned, and the docs do mention that SOQL in a trigger will scan a maximum of 100k records. So my questions are:

1. For SOQL, is this the limit in all execution contexts?
2. What are the limits for SOSL?

Comment: Isn't the 100k records the selectivity threshold? Beyond which you must ensure you reference indexed columns in your where clause. Ie. if you are trying to select 10 records out of 200k records, a well written query will do this, not just give you what it finds in the first half of the table! Or am I missing the point of your question?

Comment: You've answered part of my question, and helped me understand my own question a bit more. So if that is the selectivity threshold, what's the threshold overall for records scanned (SOSL and SOQL)? Is there one, or is it just down to timeouts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

no it isnt.

I just ran the following query via REST API against our org

select Id from sf4twitter__Twitter_Conversation_*c where sf4twitter*_IsDirectMessage__c = false LIMIT 100001

. It returned a QueryLocator with the size of 100001 and as you can see it scanned on a non indexed checkbox field. So I assume that you are limited by the request timeout rather than the actual row limit when it comes to QueryLocators.

**UPDATE::**

just ran the following query successfully
select Id from sf4twitter__Twitter_Conversation_*c where sf4twitter*_IsDirectMessage__c = false LIMIT 900000

BUT as it turns out there's not record with sf4twitter_*IsDirectMessage*_c=true so maybe the filter gets skipped

Comment: Seb - were there actually > 100,000 records in the table? I have a feeling you can do what you've done if there aren't the records in the table. If you have more than 100k records, you can prove me wrong :)

Comment: @GBreavin it contains 3M records

Comment: I wonder if the QueryLocator genuinely "scanned" the full 3M or if it just picked up the first chunk of matching records and used information it already had about the distribution of data to know that it could provide you additional chunks to your requested limit of 100001.

Comment: @DougB interesting question

Comment: Seb__Wagner has just successfully run the query returning 900k results, it seems to only be limited by timeout for SOQL. This is black magic! Would be great to know more.

Comment: QueryLocator can return 50M I think, but that is not quite the same as scanning that many records at once... each invocation of QueryMore will surely have a much smaller set of data to search in order to bring back the next chunk of records.

Comment: The selectivity requirement is only enforced in triggers. Outside of triggers you're only really bound by the timeout limits on the request.

Answer (score 3):

There's a cheat sheet that spills the beans on the exact numbers: 1 million rows for standard indexes, or 333333 rows for custom indexes (like external ID, or those requested through support) in most cases.

This also means that even filtering on indexed columns with large amounts of like data might still not result in a selective query.

Reference: http://s3.amazonaws.com/dfc-wiki/en/images/0/0e/Db-query-search-optimization-cheat-sheet.pdf

Comment: Thanks! Is it the same for SOSL?

Comment: Not sure, I can't find any docs on the details there, but I suspect it's a totally different infrastructure (heard rumors it's apache solr based rather than oracle queries).

Answer (score 1):

For SOQL, the reference I would look at is http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm
In particular the section on selective queries
"For best performance, SOQL queries must be selective, particularly for queries inside of triggers. To avoid long execution times, non-selective SOQL queries may be terminated by the system. Developers will receive an error message when a non-selective query **in a trigger** executes against an object that contains more than 100,000 records. To avoid this error, ensure that the query is selective."
This would imply that the limit is per query not per context for SOQL. Good practice to make selective queries where you can against large tables though.

Comment: It would be great to get a definition of "scanned" :) I understand the principles of selectivity and large data volumes, but I'm interested in knowing the upper bound on the number of records SFDC can look at whilst trying to find your results. Another post here shows proof that 100k isn't the limit via API, so maybe it is executional context that matters?

Comment: Yeah it's not that clear. My thinking would be that where you use indexes you reduce the set of results that require "scanned". You want Mr. Smith born 1/1/74. So if you have 5M customers and you index on lastName you might only have to "scan" the 40k with the surname of Smith to find the ones with birthday of 1/1/74. Although I guess there are some extra tricks SF have up their sleeves for optimising large tables.

Comment: There's a great doc [here](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/en/cce/ldv_deployments/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.pdf), but it doesn't deal with this precise area.